# My margin:10px auto; for my logo image its not working correctly

Tags: html, css

I have a logo at center of my hader, that is a gif image.

My gif image in details appears with 842X595 dimensions.

But when I put my image in my website, the image is very small, I dont understnad why.

So, I need to  change width and height of my image, and Im saying in css that my image should have 400px of width and 300px of height.

And I want above my image margin of 10px, and below my image margin of 10px.

I want something like my image 1:

**Image 1**

[image]

But Im getting what I have in my image 2, where I have a big white space arround my image, and I dont want this.

Do you know why this can be happening???

**Image 2:**

[image]

I have my issue in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zc6hJ/

My html:

```
<body>
<a name="topo"/>
<header id="topo-container">
    <div id="topo">
      <a href=""><img src="http://s9.postimg.org/zcjt6m1tr/logo_web2.gif"/></a>

    </div>
</header>
<section id="menu-container">   
   <nav id="menu">
   </nav>
</section>
</body>
```

Css:

```
*
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:none;
    background:#ccc;
}

#topo-container{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}

#topo{width:100%;
    margin:10px auto; }

#topo img {
    margin:10px auto;
    display:block;
    width:400px;
    height:300px; 
    background:yellow;
}

#menu-container
{
    width:100%;
    height:62px;
    float:left;
    background:red;  
    z-index:7;
    float:left;
}

#menu
{
    width:1160px;
    height:auto;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;

}
```

Comment: Is this even valid HTML? Can you have elements with equivalent `name` attributes?

Comment: The actual image itself has a white background.

Comment: Lol , your image has that white space!

Comment: The top image example shows the dimensions as 120px x 90px?

Comment: My image dont have that white background. I guess it was the site I use to host image that put that background. In my example I dont have that background!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're having is that *the picture itself* has a lot of white space around it. I copied your photo and [cropped it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYZ8P.jpg) or you crop it how you want it.